# Data Factory Extremely Slow Binary Transfer (4GB) from FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm working with Azure Data Factory to copy .txt files from an FTP site. I'm using a binary transfer approach leveraging binary formats, but ADF is showing incredibly slow throughput (90KB/s) so is taking hours to transfer a 4GB file, which isn't particularly large.

The FTP site is in the US while ADF is located in Europe, but I'm able to download from a VM in the same Europe data center and retrieve the file from FTP in a few minutes. It seems like something is not quite right, any idea why ADF is not able to retrieve a 4GB .txt file? I'm copying to BLOB and am using Azure IR for compute.

The pipeline is running 6-7 hours which seems absurd for a reasonably sized file. I have tried different formats (reading directly as delimited), etc. but it continues to be absurdly slow. I'm assuming the FTP has reasonable download speeds considering I can retrieve the file from a desktop after 4-5 minutes. When monitoring the load in the ADF monitoring I can see it is continually "reading from source" though I can see the data read amount is not changing so I'm wondering if it is dropping a connection, etc.

Any thoughts would help!

Comment: What is the configuration of your Self Hosted IR? IR also plays a huge role in such data transfers

Comment: @PratikSomaiya I am using Azure IR so there should be no infrastructure configuration impact.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this by, instead of using binary transfer, reading in native format (delimited) and then write out in chunked up parquet in BLOB. I've set a max number of rows for the write out files so it's forcing physical files to be committed.

For whatever reason, it was struggling trying to read the entire 4GB file and then write it out. It seems counterintuitive to move away from a binary copy but seems to be the only option in this case.